# Could asteroseismology have a significant potential to unravel the mechanisms of solar cycles that last thousands of years?

Tags: astronomy, stars, stellar-physics

Could [asteroseismology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroseismology) have a significant potential to unravel the mechanisms of solar cycles that last thousands of years?

And what about solar cycles 1 billion years ago and 2 billion years ago (when it's possible that the Sun had completely different solar cycles - a possible factor that no one in the geosciences seems to acknowledge yet, and which could complicate the analysis of the climate of the [Precambrian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precambrian) Earth)?

This thought is inspired by the Chaplin et al. (2011) paper *[Ensemble Asteroseismology of Solar-Type Stars with the NASA Kepler Mission](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/332/6026/213.abstract)*.

Comment: not to nit-pick ... but when you're dealing with the Sun / Sol / etc ... then it's [helioseismology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helioseismology), with a lot of new data coming from [HMI](http://hmi.stanford.edu/), the magnetograph on [SDO](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/).  (not to discount [GONG](http://gong.nso.edu/) and other efforts)

Comment: Yeah I know. But we only have data from the Sun at one point of its life.

Answer (score 3):

Potentially. Asteroseismology can give us a fair amount of information about the activity of a star, and studying a large number of stars could help us knit together more robust theories of stellar activity and development. However, there's only so much asteroseismology tells us, we learn as much or more merely from studying our own star with a wider range of instrumentation.

Also, it may be that it will take building up decades or even centuries of accurate asteroseismological histories of a great number of stars to really begin to understand stellar evolution on a fine scale.